# How set a variable in Mysql from Visual Basic .net using parametrized Value from a Texbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have this store procedure and works just fine but I need pass the variable "@item" from Visual Basic .net the code works using direct query but it's to messy and unsecure I need parametrize, send the value from textbox.

```
SET @item = '@vbitem';
SELECT
rm_users.username,
rm_users.enableuser,
rm_users.firstname,
rm_users.lastname,
rm_users.company,
rm_users.phone,
rm_users.mobile,
rm_users.address,
rm_users.city,
rm_users.srvid,
rm_users.staticipcpe,
rm_users.contractid,
rm_users.email,
radacct.nasipaddress,
radacct.callingstationid,
radacct.framedipaddress,
rm_wlan.maccpe,
rm_wlan.ccq,
rm_wlan.`signal`,
rm_wlan.snr,
rm_wlan.apip,
rm_wlan.`timestamp`,
nas.nasname,
nas.shortname,
radacct.acctstoptime
FROM
rm_users
INNER JOIN radacct ON rm_users.username = radacct.username
INNER JOIN rm_wlan ON radacct.callingstationid = rm_wlan.maccpe
INNER JOIN nas ON radacct.nasipaddress = nas.nasname
WHERE
rm_users.username LIKE @item OR
rm_users.firstname LIKE @item OR
rm_users.lastname LIKE @item OR
rm_users.city LIKE @item OR
rm_users.address LIKE @item OR
rm_users.taxid LIKE @item OR
rm_users.company LIKE @item OR
radacct.callingstationid LIKE @item
GROUP BY
rm_users.username
ORDER BY
rm_users.username ASC here
```

---

Visual Basic code extract

```
         cmd = New MySqlCommand("procedure-name")
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vbitem", textbox.Text)
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sproc has an `@item` parameter then you should get rid of that first line in the sproc and then just set the `@item` parameter in VB code, i.e.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", textbox.Text)
```

Comment: But I must set in proc SET @item = '@item'; or leave it like I have it the post?

Comment: Um, neither.  You do what I said: get rid of that first line altogether.  If you have declared a parameter in your sproc named `@item` then the line of VB code I provided is what sets the value of that parameter.  You don't do it manually in the SQL code.

Comment: I did it in this way                                                    `code` cmd = New MySqlCommand("show_all")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", tbsearch.Text)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure my question is I must remove this from proc                  `code`BEGIN
SET @item = @item;
SELECT

Comment: Given that I've already told you twice to remove that line, why exactly are you still asking that question?